# Android Context.startActivity(Intent) throws runtime exception

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

My pet Android app on Google Play was crashing and the stack trace from Google Play Console doesn't show the exception error message. I am left perplexed over how a startActivity call could throw a runtime exception.

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:922)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:898)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity (ContextWrapper.java:389)
  at com.muchen.tweetstormmaker.views.DraftAdapter$DraftViewHolder.lambda$new$0 (DraftAdapter.java:8)
  at com.muchen.tweetstormmaker.views.-$$Lambda$DraftAdapter$DraftViewHolder$XO1lmnEfxZyiTl39GhDThT2OKHw.onClick (-.java:2)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6608)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:6585)
  at android.view.View.access$3100 (View.java:785)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:25921)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:201)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6810)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Here's the piece of code that calls startActivity. I can't see what's wrong with it.

```
            itemView.setOnClickListener((view)->{
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DraftEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_DRAFT_ID,
                        drafts.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDraftId());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            });
```

Code of the enclosing java class is here: https://github.com/mchen118/tweetstorm-maker-android-java/blob/issue_1/app/src/main/java/com/muchen/tweetstormmaker/views/DraftAdapter.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startActivity()` can throw an `AndroidRuntimeException` like this one:

```java
            throw new AndroidRuntimeException(
                    "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity "
                            + " context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag."
                            + " Is this really what you want?");
```

`context`, apparently, is not always an `Activity`.

And, in fact, it is not an `Activity`, based on your `master` branch code at the time I answered this question. You seem to be creating it via:

```java
draftAdapter = new DraftAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

Only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know why you are using the `Application`. And, in general, for UI concerns, always use an `Activity` as the `Context`:

```java
draftAdapter = new DraftAdapter(this);
```

Comment: Just a follow-on to this answer.  Android is open source and you can always just look at the code for [ContextImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#969) as CommonsWare has done.

Comment: @MichaelKrause: Yup, that's what I did... though I used [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java;l=174?q=ContextImpl&sq=).